# Is the space complexity of a recursive algorithm necessarily at least as large as the depth of the recursive call?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

I am having trouble determining when recursive functions are sub-optimal to their iterative counterparts when space is an issue. When writing recursive functions, is the space complexity necessarily at least as large as the depth of the recursive call if it is not tail recursive?

For example, lets remove duplicates from a linked list using recursion. This can be done trivially with an iterative approach in O(n^2) time and O(1) space. But is the recursive variant also O(1) space?

```
removeDuplicatesRecursive() {
    let current = this.head;

    while (current.next) {
      if (this.head.data === current.next.data) {
        current.next = current.next.next
      } else {
        current = current.next;
      }
    }

    if (this.head.next) {
      removeDuplicatesRecursive(this.head.next);
    }

    return head;
  }
```

Comment: Your recursive algorithm does not make sense. `removeDuplicatesRecursive()` is written as a member method yet you call it statically and pass an argument that is unused.

Comment: In addition, consider why Stack Overflow errors exist. If recursion was O(1) space, why is there a limit to how many times you can recurse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above program, the space complexity is `O(n)`.

For recursion, until you reach the base condition, every call to the recursive function including all the arguments, local variables are put into call stack.

For the above program, the most number of function calls will happen when all the elements of the linked list are unique. In that case, `n` function calls will be made and space complexity will be `O(n)`.

Comment: `the worst case of space complexity happens, when all the elements of the linked list are unique.` _If_ the above method was implemented properly, it would _always_ reach the worst case of space complexity, because it _always_ recurses the entire linked list. This is not conditional on whether the elements are unique.

Comment: When there will be some duplicates, those elements will be deleted so there will be no call for those elements. In big-O perspectives, yes it will be always `O(n)`.

Comment: That makes more sense; for some reason I wasn't considering the removed elements as limiting the number of calls.

Comment: @KaidulIslam What is the `c` in your answer in c*n if `n` is the number of recursive calls?

Comment: @MarcFletcher I basically put `c` to denote that the space needed in the function stack for each call is not constant always, because inside method, there can be some static/dynamic memory allocation take place. However, for your program, its strictly `O(n)`. I edited my answer anyway to remove confusion.